# Difference between a convergent series and an asymptotic series?

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, perturbation-theory

Can someone let me know the difference between a convergent series and an asymptotic series with an example? Can both the series be the same at some situations? In what situations an asymptotic series is more useful?

Answer (score 3):

A convergent series
gets closer to the sum
as more terms are taken.

A asymptotic series
initially gets closer to the sum
but,
after a while,
gets increasingly further away
and usually ultimately diverges.
In many asymptotic series,
the error is less than the
last term. Since the terms eventually
get large, the usual practice
is to stop the series
when the terms no longer decrease

A classic example
of an asymptotic series is
Stirling's formula.
One of many discussions is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation